# How can I move the start menu / task bar to a secondary display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, taskbar, netbook, windows-xp

I have a netbook using Windows XP, with a secondary monitor attached. Both monitors are configured and working correctly.

What I would like to do is  move the start menu and the task bar over to the secondary display (monitor number 2). I can't find any obvious means of doing this. Is it possible, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right click on start bar, unselect "Lock the taskbar".  Now simply drag it to an edge of the screen on the other monitor, it should stick there.

Comment: Thanks :) I haven't used Windows in a long time, its weird getting used to it again. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Windows 8 and 8.1: to move Start Screen from one display to another use `Windows logo key + Page Up` key combination.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: My answer relates to this part of question: **How can I move the start menu**. Since Start Menu evolved into Start Screen in Windows 8, I provided the answer for that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the start menu and taskbar from the first display to the second display by assigning your "primary display" in the Display Properties (right from click desktop).

However, if you want to have the taskbar on both display, you need to get a third party program to do that. Some of these will let you put the start menu on both screens if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AMD gpu then use the control center . under AMD Eyefinity Multi-Display - there is an option for it - Position Windows Taskbar . I would assume those who use Nvidia gpu's would have something similar .